# Passing arguments from a function to an internal function in Java?

Tags: java, function, arguments

EDIT: To clarify, I want the java equivalent of the python code.

How do I pass all the arguments from a function to another function that is called within it. This was possible in Python in the following way:

```
def p(*args):
    print(*args)
```

I know multiple arguments can be passed in Java using `Object... objects`
But I don't know how to pass them to the internal function by "unpacking"  the array. One example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
public static void printf(Objects object) {
    System.out.printf(objects)
    //I don't believe that this works, but it's the jist of what I want to do
}
```

Is there a better way to do something like this or a more Java-like way?

Comment: why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: You can create object and store all variable there, but I think in your case use `*args` is better

Comment: @Mritunjay because System.out.printf doesn't take arrays as an argument I think. 

`public static void printf(Object... o) {
    System.out.printf(o);
 }` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific case of `System.out.printf`, this is very possible. Because `printf` has an argument list of `(String, Object...)`. You can do this:

```
private static void foo(String s, Object... objs) {
    System.out.printf(s, objs);
}
```

You can basically pass an argument of type `Object...` to another method that requires a `Object...` or `Object[]`.

However, what you can't do is to pass an `Object...` to a method expecting 5 `Object`s.

```
private static void foo(Object... objs) {
    bar(objs)
}

private static void bar(Object a, Object b, Object c, Object d, Object e) {

}
```

You have to pass the arguments one by one:

```
bar(objs[0], objs[1], objs[2], objs[3], objs[4]);
```

Comment: You mention that this works for a specific case of `System.out.printf`. Doesn't the first argument always need to be a string? What case would it not work for?

Comment: if the argument list is something else, like I showed at the end of the answer, you need to access each element of the array. You can't just pass `objs`. @sblack

Answer (score 0):

You can use ...

```
public static void foo(Object... args) {
for (Object arg : args) {
    System.out.println(arg); // do something here 
 }
}
```

Call it from where you want like this

`foo("1", "2", "3" , 1 , 1.2 , 1231 , "hello"); // you can pass as many as you want`

Comment: But that wouldn't work for something like System.out.printf which is the example I provided.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass all the args along:

```
def func1(*args):
    print 'Hi, my name is func1'
    print 'Now I will call func2 with all args'
    func2(*args)
```

Or if you only want to pass some args:

```
def func1(*args):
    print 'Hi, my name is func1'
    print 'Now I will call func2 with only two args'
    func2(args[1], args[5])
```

Comment: I don't want help with python. I want the java equivalent of the python code.